# ImportError: cannot import name 'PrioritizedFields' from 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models'

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Trying this tutorial - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-semantic?tabs=python - I am getting error `ImportError: cannot import name 'PrioritizedFields' from 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models' (c:\....\demo-data\aoai-openai\aoai-code\.venv\Lib\site-packages\azure\search\documents\indexes\models\__init__.py)` when I execute cell

```
%pip install azure-search-documents --pre --upgrade
%pip show azure-search-documents
%pip install python-dotenv

import os
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient 
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import (  
    SearchIndex,  
    SearchField,  
    SearchFieldDataType,  
    SimpleField,  
    SearchableField,
    ComplexField,
    SearchIndex,  
    SemanticConfiguration,  
    PrioritizedFields,  
    SemanticField,  
    SemanticSettings,  
)
```

Why am I getting the error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

seems the field name changed to `SemanticPrioritizedFields` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.indexes.models?view=azure-python